# Slideshow with no fade out

Tags: jquery, slideshow, fadeout

I have a slideshow with a couple of images. It works, but with one small disadvantage. The images all fade out. Let me explain: the first image fades in and fades out again. The second image then fades in and fades out. Followed by the third image, which fades in and out again.
The problem is that in between the fading out of the first image and fading in of the second image, nothing is showed. I want to fade in the first image and then fade in the second image on top of the first one and so on. That way, theres no 'nothing' in between the fading of the images.

How do i adapt the following code?

html:

```
<div class="slideshow"></div>
```

Javascript

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
var images=new Array('http://placehold.it/450x450','http://placehold.it/250x150/123456','http://placehold.it/250x150/dbca98');
var nextimage=0;

doSlideshow();

function doSlideshow()
{
    if($('.slideshowimage').length!=0)
    {
        $('.slideshowimage').fadeOut(1500,function(){slideshowFadeIn();$(this).remove()});
    }
    else
    {
        slideshowFadeIn();
    }
}
function slideshowFadeIn()
{
    $('.slideshow').prepend($('<img class="slideshowimage" src="'+images[nextimage++]+'" style="display:none">').fadeIn(1500,function(){setTimeout(doSlideshow,1500);}));
    if(nextimage>=images.length)
        nextimage=0;
}
});//]]>  

</script>
```

Css

```
<style type='text/css'>
    .slideshow
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 455px;
    height: 450px;
}
.slideshow img
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 455px;
    height: 450px;
    z-index:1;
}
  </style>
```

You can find the code at fiddle: [script](http://jsfiddle.net/R4ZHX/)

Comment: there is a great plugin for this http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is move your 'slideshowFadeIn';

http://jsfiddle.net/R4ZHX/195/

```
if($('.slideshowimage').length!=0)
{
    $('.slideshowimage').fadeOut(1500,function(){$(this).remove()});
    slideshowFadeIn();
}
else
{
    slideshowFadeIn();
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to do the job. Tried it, but it crashes my browser.

Comment: What browser, version and OS?

It works well in Chrome, FF and Safari.

Comment: Tested it in IE8 as well in win7. Works there as well. Not sure why your browser would crash.

Comment: Tried it with firefox 3.0.19 windows vista. Also tried it on my iphone and ipad. It seems to work the first cycle, but then it looks like it hangs and my browser crashes.

Answer (score 0):

There are functions being called doing exactly that... for a cheap solution put slideshowFadeIn() under the fadeOut() call in your first "if" statement.

Comment: Doesn't seem to do the job. Tried it, but it crashes my browser.